# Load trained model and run testing in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, scikit-learn, weka

I need to run the classification step in NodeJS.

I could train the model from data offline in Python, and save to a suitable file format (either pickle, json or csv). Which package in NodeJS allows loading and then run inference?

I found [scikit-node](https://github.com/lramsey/scikit-node), [scikit-learn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scikit-learn), or [node-weka](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-weka), but it seems that none of these packages could load the trained model.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I haven't found any library which supports SVM. [KerasJS](https://github.com/transcranial/keras-js) can be used in JS environment to run models trained by [Keras Deep Learning Library](https://keras.io/).